# refresh a shell subprocess in python

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I have a webpy code that sends "ps aux" data to a webpage using a subprocess.

```
import subprocess
ps = subprocess.Popen(('ps', 'aux'), stdout-subprocess.PIPE)
out = ps.communicate()[0]

(bunch of webpy stuff)
class index:
    def GET(self):
        return (output)
(more webpy to start the web server)
```

It sends the ps aux data across no problem however it does not refresh the ps aux data so i only get 1 continuous set rather than a changing set of data i am needing.

How do i refresh the subprocess to send new data every time I reload the webpage ?

Comment: You would have to call the function again

Comment: you could [use `psutil` to get the process info](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil). See also [how `glances -s` server and `glances --browser` works](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `Popen` call into the `def GET`. By the way, if you’re using Python 2.7 or newer, you can use [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to simplify the actual subprocess call:

```
def GET(self):
    return subprocess.check_output(['ps', 'aux'])
```